# What does "probe down" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "probe down" mean in football (soccer) context?

74 min: Richarlison **probes down** the left and wins a corner off James. Digne’s corner lands in a crowded box but somehow avoids everyone. The ball eventually sails away from the danger zone.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to have a bit more context to work with here, but if it is something like a soccer / football game, the interpretation is clear.

The "probe" and "down" can be viewed separately:

- "Probe" is used in the sense of "test" or "feel", as the intransitive verb described [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probe).
- "Down" is used to describe the direction of motion, as in "He ran down the field." In the context of a soccer / football game. Adverb meaning 2b at [this site](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down) is probably closest, although I would assume it means Richarlison is moving toward the goal his opponents are defending.

Together in context, the phrase "probes down" suggests Richarlison is moving cautiously toward the opposing goal and is expecting defenders to interrupt or stop him.

Comment: thanks. In your sentence "it **would** be nice to have a bit more context to work with here." You used "would", so how does **would** work?

Comment: I used it to express a wish. You are not required to edit your question. If my answer does not make sense, try making the quoted text longer. The "possibility" examples at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would are relevant. I think this is an example of the "subjunctive" clause. See https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm for related constructions and examples.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand. Is it a past form of "will'? Or " would" in your sentence means to want

Comment: In this context, "would" draws contrast between reality and an imagined world. In reality, "Richarlison probes down the left and wins a corner off James." is the sentence you provided. In the imaginary world I described, there is "more context". That "context" is a longer quote or additional information. The "It would be nice" construction says the imaginary world is better than the real one.